# Which Virtual machine is used in Android 11?

Tags: dalvik, art, vm

Every Android application runs in a virtual machine. We know that Dalvik virtual machine \was the one that is used by Android.  Next, they changed to ART (Android Runtime machine). Just correct me if I am wrong. Android 11 uses which virtual machine, Dalvik or ART?

Comment: ART replaced Dalvik in Android 5. Dalvik VM is no more used.

Answer (score 1):

Android 11 uses ART.  Android 4.x KitKat were the last Android releases to use Dalvik.

Comment: @Mdshammi111 You're welcome.  Glad to help.  BTW, Wikipedia has good articles on both Dalvik and ART, and the transition from one to the other.

Comment: Can u suggest to me some textbooks regarding the android source?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not currently know of any.  The source is available online, but I'm not aware of any textbooks that walk you through it.  Perhaps someone else will know of one.